# Custom ImageView shape drawable in xml like this one in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-canvas

I want to create an ImageView like this one. I know it's a combination of a rectangle and a triangle shape,

[but I really don't know how to implement it.](http://s32.postimg.org/y771xz445/exchange_blue_img.png)

Is it possible in XML?. Does layer-list seem to help in this case?. I would like to have some example drawable xml codes

Answer (score 0):

In XML you can create:

- rectangle
- oval
- ring
- line
- gradient
- and more

Image like [this](http://s32.postimg.org/y771xz445/exchange_blue_img.png) difficult or impossible create in XML, try use vector (.svg) files

[Convert .PNG to .SVG](http://vectormagic.com/home)

P.S. you can create image like this:

[image: rectangle]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#EC6118"/>
            <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
                 android:bottomLeftRadius="0.1dip"
                 android:topLeftRadius="7dip"
                 android:topRightRadius="0.1dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: can you tell me best svg library in android? @Nikita G.

Comment: you can read about this http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/help/vector-asset-studio.html @Georgo